# Image Crop From URL

Tags: php, jquery, image, url, crop

Hi I've been working with the iTunes API and what I've done is saved the data that's returned from the search into the database. I'm saving the iTunes image URL to my database and I'm wondering what would be the best method to crop the image from the URL with PHP, or is it better to crop the image with jQuery before I display the images on the site? Thanks in advance for you advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to crop images server-side, probably. Cropping client side means the client is going to have to load the whole image, and that will slow down page loads (potentially a lot, depending on how big the images are).

Cropping server-side means that you'll have to save the cropped images to your server and serve them from there. This is more of a pain than just doing the cropping client-side, but it will probably be better for your users in the end.

Since you're using PHP, you want [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropimage.php).

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that thanks for confirmation and the link to imagemagick that looks great exactly what I've been looking for thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Full step-by-step tutorial to crop image using jQuery & php (included live demo)

http://www.script-tutorials.com/image-crop-plugin-using-jcrop-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

It is best to crop and store the cropped versions on the server, that way the images load faster and you save a lot of bandwidth.